# Запутанные метки [голоса-за], [голоса-против], [голосование]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, мета, голосование

У нас есть [голоса-за](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0), [голоса-против](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2), [голосование](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Если хочу опубликовать вопрос по поводу системы голосования на основном сайте, то, вполне логично, захочу использовать метку [голосование](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Вот только эта метка по поводу голосований по предложениям на мете. Т.е, мне в таком случае придётся использовать и [голоса-за](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0), и [голоса-против](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2).

Может сделаем что-нибудь с этими метками?

Comment: Судя по тому что я вижу, обычно метку "голосование" ставили для вопросов про голосования, а голосования на мете - лишь погрешность.

Comment: @PavelMayorov именно. Я сам недавно удивился описанию)

Comment: @Suvitruf Отредактировал некорректные использования метки.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я смотрю, кто-то тут голоса поменял D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переписать описание метки [голосование](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и использовать её для вопросов про систему голосований. Для голосований на мете не использовать никакой спец. метки.

Answer (score 5):

Переписать описание метки [голосование](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и использовать её для вопросов про систему голосований. Для голосований на мете создать другую метку, например, [мета-голосование](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Answer (score 3):

Оставить всё как есть. [голосование](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) как и прежде будет для мета вопросов с голосованием.

Answer (score -4):

Удалить метку [голосование](/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) вообще.